# How to get the ignored column in the existing joined data table in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have joined two data tables with full outer join in Spotfire and ignored some columns but now I need those columns in my report so how can I get those columns?

I have tried to join the same data table with existing joined data table but it is decreasing performance speed.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have done & subsequently tried. This helps the community help debug your issue.

Comment: Hi Rishabh- which version of Spotfire are you using?